# which algorithms can be used for feature identification and extraction from text for morhphological tasks like inflection

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering

I am trying to learn morphology of words and I am trying to cluster the words based on the morpho features of the word like number gender etc but these binary features are alone not sufficient . I have unlabelled corpus and I would like to extract features for these inflection tasks . I am unaware of any such algorithms.

I dont think word2vec(or globve) will work as it is word and the morphology of the word is not taken into consideration.

Any method for placing words into vector space that can get the words with similar syntax and inflection together in vector space.